# Downloading links in a for loop in different folders selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of folders' name `Folder_names` which contain folders names say `['Week1',Week2','Week3']`.

And I have a list of hyperlinks stored in `hyper_link_of_files` variable.

Each of these links needs to be clicked (once you click on this link it automatically downloads the file into the download folder).

In a for loop, I want to download each link to the newly created folder

I tried the following but did not work

```
for j in range(len(Folder_names)):
    # Create a new folder
    os.mkdir(Folder_names[j])
    path_needed=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),Folder_names[i])
    # click to download file into a particular folder python selenium
    href1=hyper_link_of_files[j]
    driver.execute_script("window.open('%s', '_blank')" % href1)
    # Save it into the new path_needed
```

What I want is to download each of the links to the allocated file.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is as following:

1. For each link create a folder, as you already doing.
2. Click the link to download the link content (I guess it's some file downloaded) to the default downloads folder.
3. Move the downloaded file to the dedicated folder.

This should work clear and stable. No need to re-define the downloads folder for Selenium, just move the downloaded file to the dedicated folder.